# Salesforce send Email by Apex

Tags: email, salesforce, apex

I'm making by a requirement a code able to send an E-mail to an specific list of E-mails, due the fact that I must to include the attachments of the record I decided to use an apex class instead an e-mail alert. This object (A custom object ) must populate some fields in an email template with some of the record´s fields. I implemented the following code

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
mail.setToAddresses(lista); 
mail.setTemplateId('00X21000000QR22');
//mail.setWhatId(idMinuta);
mail.setTargetObjectId('005d0000005NMIx');
mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();
for (ContentVersion document: documents) 
{
   Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
   efa.setFileName(document.Title);
   efa.setBody(document.VersionData);   
   fileAttachments.add(efa);
}
mail.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

I understood that to make the fields merge it´s necesary to use the WhatId method. In the related code, I have commented it because It generates an error (INVALID_ID_FIELD, WhatId is not available for sending emails to UserIds.)

My question is,  if is it possible to do this with a custom object. I´m a little confuse with salesforce documentation beacuse it looks like the method supports a custom object, or maybe If I am forggeting something to include in the code.

[image]

If i keep the WhatID line commented, effectively the email is sent with the attachments and the Template but it is not populated.

I really need this kind of solution because the org have in this object at least 20 email templates, for me will be easier just to pass the Id of the template instead of makig a code with 20 different html codes for each situation

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Please publish this question at Salesforce StackExcahnge https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/